# failed to install vagrant-cachier plugin on windows

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows, vagrant-plugin, vagrant-cachier

I am new to `vagrant`.

I have installed virtualbox and `vagrant`(1.7.4) and then follow the book type

```
$> vagrant plugin install vagrant-cachier
```

After some minutes,it reported an error:

```
> vagrant plugin install vagrant-cachier
Installing the 'vagrant-cachier' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

An error occurred while installing childprocess (0.5.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install childprocess -v '0.5.7'` succeeds before bundling.

Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more than once without a block is a security risk, and may result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems should come from the secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A (https://rubygems.org/gems/childprocess-0.5.7.gem)
```

I know little about `ruby` and `gem`.Is there anything else need to be installed before install plugins?
Or maybe the network issue? (I tried at home and office,the same error)
vagrant works fine that I can init, up and ssh normally.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue finding it is a matter of gems folder misconfiguration.
I solved it with the following steps:

1. check where are your gems inside your vagrant installation (e.g. `%vagrant_home%/embedded/gems/gems`)
2. check your gem configuration with the command `gem environment` and looking for the section named GEM PATHS (if gem is not in you path look for it under the vagrant installation folder, e.g. `%vagrant_home%/embedded/bin`)
3. if the path at point 1 is not present within the section at point 2, include it with the command `export GEM_HOME=/path/to/gems/folder` (e.g. `export GEM_HOME=%vagrant_home%/embedded/gems/gems`)

P.S. `%vagrant_home%` refers to the vagrant installation base folder, use set instead of export under windows ...and sorry if I mixed unix and windows syntaxes

Test Environment: Vagrant 1.8.1 (gem 2.4.5.1) on Windows 7 behind web proxy

Answer (score 0):

I installed this plugin https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd and now Vagrant Cachier works like a charm on Windows 10.

To run it on Ubuntu simply install the nfs-server 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52361432/1679541