# When “vagrant up” it says “It appears your machine doesn't support NFS” (Debian jessie)

Tags: linux, vagrant, debian, virtualbox, debian-jessie

## Issue

when `vagrant up` it says "It appears your machine doesn't support NFS"

## Setups

- Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie）
- Vagrant 1:2.0.0
- Virtualbox 5.1.30 r118389

## Detail

After using apt-get to update and upgrade the system, I basically followed the instruction from the [Mediawiki page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki-Vagrant), since I wanted to install [Mathoid](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Mathoid) to render LaTeX equations locally for mediawiki page.

However, when I `vagrant up` it echos the following:

```
It appears your machine doesn't support NFS, or there is not an
adapter to enable NFS on this machine for Vagrant. Please verify
that `nfsd` is installed on your machine, and try again. If you're
on Windows, NFS isn't supported. If the problem persists, please
contact Vagrant support.
```

I checked if nfsd is correctly working on the host, and it says it's enabled.

```
# /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server status
nfs-kernel-server.service - LSB: Kernel NFS server support
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server)
Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-10-15 07:56:32 -02; 2 weeks 0 days ago
CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-kernel-server.service
       ??1277 /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd --manage-gids
```

I also tried google, and did not find a solution that fits my problem and I couldn't find any hint to resolve this. For instance, I tried to install the package

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

But it has been already installed.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can be fixed by adding any exports to /etc/exports.

by :

```
   modprobe nfs
   modprobe nfsd
```

then running vagrant, which will add `/etc/exports`, then reloading 
**kernel-server** and **restarting vagrant**.

issue http://jb-blog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/posts/0021-vagrant-nfs-problems.html

instead of installed NFS cos really no supported :

Try just removing `type: nfs` from the `vagrant_synced_folders`

More : https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html

Comment: welcome i am on debian jessie x64 I7 the first solution solve me the problem.

Comment: After freezing the system once and had the fear that it has to be reinstalled from scratch, I gave up. I need to really learn the notions of vagrant and virtualbox first, simply following guide did not get me anywhere. Therefore, unfortunately, this stuff is beyond my capability.. Many thanks for the helps!

Comment: lol i hope you take sufficient knowledge to drive vagrant property as good OP can do it, ty for the report. gby

Answer (score 45):

The command mentioned below works for linux mint 18.3:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
```

Comment: Worked for me as well. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 20):

For **Windows** users seeing that error, run the following command to add support for NFS for Vagrant:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd
```

The GitHub repo for this plugin is found [here](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd).

Also, to see the currently installed Vagrant plugins run this:

```
vagrant plugin list
```